# How to "route" to PHP methods?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP class with a number of public methods. I'm not in a PHP framework environment, so I don't have the option to access methods via URL routes that's common in frameworks (e.g. `domain.com/myclass/mymethod/`). However, I do want to be able to call those methods directly via Ajax.

How can I do this? Can Ajax POST some parameters to the class to instantiate it and call the appropriate method and pass it the parameters the method needs?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to try using `spl_autoload_register()` instead?

Comment: No, you'll need something (ie, a PHP script) to instantiate your class instance and route the requests to the appropriate methods

Comment: So just like a framework you'll take that url that is rewritten to something available in the `$_GET` superglobal and then use that info to call the class/method.

Comment: How to do this? Do I POST to the PHP file and does the constructor then have access to the POST vars?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define your routing in .htaccess to route all requests to a specific file which in turn will instantiate the necessary classes and calls the functions. Its just like what Phil and AbraCadaver said. You however will need a .htaccess to route your requests to that file.

Also you will have to enable Apache mod_rewrite. URL rewriting is handled using apache's mod_rewrite.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is only if OP wants to use friendly URLs which in the case of AJAX calls from JavaScript, isn't really necessary